# Controller has a lot of @Autowired services

Tags: java, spring, performance, rest, spring-mvc

I combined all my REST API methods in one controller, and each method requires its own service.
So I have about 15 `@Autowired` annotated fields for services in one controller.

Is that right thing to do at all?

Will it affect the performance of my REST controller?
Should I divide all methods between 2 or more separate controllers?
What is optimal amount of `@Autowired` in class to avoid affecting performance?

Comment: if it is singleton, there won't be any performance drop at all. There may be some performance drop if controller itself is prototype- or request-scoped and @Autowired services are also non-singleton and require heavy initialization.

Comment: There is no negative performance impact. But you should split your controller in order to increase the understandability.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to split API methods between multiple controllers but not due performance hazards (supercontroller may be even faster) - it is about preventing future maintainability issues.

Answer (score 3):

You have nothing to worry about in terms of performance. Spring is just giving you a reference to the bean that you declared within your Spring Configuration

But you might want to consider dividing your methods between more controllers in order to make your code more readable & maintainable.

Take a look at your current controller and see if you can group the methods logically.